# Как записать в BitArray строку?

Tags: c#

Дана строка `"0010"`, как записать ее в `BitArray`, чтобы получилось `{false, false, true, false}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cs
string bits = "0010";
BitArray bitArray = new BitArray(bits.Select(x => x == '1').ToArray());
Console.WriteLine("{" + string.Join(", ", bitArray.Cast<bool>()) + "}");
```

Вывод в консоль

```
{False, False, True, False}
```